# Increase height of UITableViewCell separator

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, separator

I have subclassed and colored tableview cells in a tableview that is on a view with an image.  What I need to do is increase the height of the cell separators.  I know this has been asked before, but the difference is that I cannot add a view at the bottom of my cells because I need the area to be transparent so I can see the image under the tableview.  Each cell is populated with data from CoreData.

Is there any way to increase the height of the tableview separators without simply creating a blank 'filler' cell between each populated cell, or creating a new section with a footer for each cell?

Basically, what I need is a new Cell Separator Style similar to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine but more than a single line.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, we will add a image view as the background view of the table cell. An example of the image is: a three pixel height image, 2 pixel transparent and 1 pixel black, which will be stretched as the separator.

Comment: I actually did it a little differently than what you explained, but you gave me the inspiration.  What I did was increase the cell height, but add a view on TOP of the cell in IB.  I made this view 5 pixels shorter than the cell height.  I then placed all of my subviews on top of this view.  This allowed me to color the view on top of the cell, while leaving the taller cell underneath clear, giving the appearance of a taller cell separator.

Answer (score 1):

for other people that may come here,

- disable separator
- add a simple label to your prototype cell
- remove the text of the label and set the width eg 2px and background color.
- stretch the label